# WCF Service Method Call from Android App

Tags: java, android, wcf, service

I need to call a WCF Service which has the SOAP Envelop as below:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">SessionStart</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:eca7579d-5581-4989-984d-0ead2e670194</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://[WCF Service URL].svc</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <XMLMessage xmlns="http://[Client Website URL]/MobileInterface">
            &lt;SessionManagementRequest&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;IMEI&gt;123456&lt;/IMEI&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;OfficerNumber&gt;AA&lt;/OfficerNumber&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;Password&gt;AA&lt;/Password&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;Status&gt;Setup&lt;/Status&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;UserName&gt;AA&lt;/UserName&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;XSDVersion&gt;1&lt;/XSDVersion&gt;&#xD;
            &lt;/SessionManagementRequest&gt;
        </XMLMessage>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The part I'm struggling with is getting the value XMLMessage SOAPObject. Below is a sample of my code:

```
public static String requestSessionManagement() throws Exception
    {
        int i;
        int timeout;
        PropertyInfo pi;
        HttpTransportSE transport;
        String soap_action;
        String method = "GetData";
        String result = "";

        timeout = ServerInterface.TIMEOUT;
        soap_action = _soap_namespace + method;

        // Check array to know if custom timeout is needed
        for (i = 0;i < func_timeouts.length;i++)
        {
            if (func_timeouts[i][0].compareTo(method) == 0)
            {
                timeout = Integer.parseInt(func_timeouts[i][1]);
            }
        }

        Log.i("[ServerInterface]", "sending request to "+_server_url+": "+_soap_namespace+method);
        Log.i("[ServerInterface]", "timeout: "+timeout);

     // Build request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(_soap_namespace, "XMLMessage");

    MapRequestSessionManagement param1 = new MapRequestSessionManagement();
    param1.imei = "123456";
    param1.officer_number = "1029384";
    param1.password = "test1!";
    param1.status = "Setup";
    param1.username = "MichaelJS";
    param1.xsd_version = "1";

    pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("SessionManagementRequest");
    pi.setValue(param1);
    pi.setType(MapRequestSessionManagement.MAPREQUESTSESSIONMANAGEMENT_CLASS);
    request.addProperty(pi);        

    // Build envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);// Soap version must match server implementation

    //Prepare header
    envelope.headerOut = new Element[4];
    envelope.headerOut[0] = ServerSyncHelper.buildActionHeader("SessionStart");
    envelope.headerOut[1] = ServerSyncHelper.buildMessageIDHeader();
    envelope.headerOut[2] = ServerSyncHelper.buildReplyToHeader("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous");
    envelope.headerOut[3] = ServerSyncHelper.buildToHeader(_server_url);

    envelope.dotNet = true; // Must set this if the server is implemented on the dotnet framework
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    // Set http transport
    transport = new HttpTransportSE(_server_url, timeout);
    transport.debug = true;  //this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent message was (httpTransport.requestDump, httpTransport.responseDump)

    try
    {

        transport.call(soap_action, envelope);
        Log.i("[ServerInterface]", "request dump "+transport.requestDump);          
        Log.i("[ServerInterface]", "response dump "+transport.responseDump);            
        Log.i("[ServerInterface]", "response "+envelope.bodyIn);

    String response = (String)envelope.getResponse();
    result = ""+response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("[ServerInterface]", "Exception part");           
        Log.i("[ServerInterface]", "request dump "+transport.requestDump);          
        Log.i("[ServerInterface]", "response dump "+transport.responseDump);
        Log.e("[ServerInterface]", "Error with soap transmition "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
    }
```

When I run the above code, I get the following results, which is correct. However, I'm not sure how to format according to what the Server requires:

```xml
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope">
    <v:Header>
        <Action v:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">SessionStart</Action>
        <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:49bd428d-188a-4035-8d8f-45bcb42b37ec</MessageID>
        <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <Address xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
        </ReplyTo>
        <To v:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://41.134.120.203/MobileInterfaceService/SessionManagementService.svc</To>
    </v:Header>
    <v:Body>
        <XMLMessage xmlns="http://www.syntell.com/MobileInterface/" id="o0" c:root="1">
            <SessionManagementRequest>
                <IMEI>123456</IMEI>
                <OfficerNumber>1029384</OfficerNumber>
                <Password>test1!</Password>
                <Status>Setup</Status>
                <UserName>MichaelJS</UserName>
                <XSDVersion>1</XSDVersion>
            </SessionManagementRequest>
        </XMLMessage>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

It seems that they've coded the Server method to accept a String Parameter which contains the XML Structure for SessionManagementRequest Object.

Comment: What do you mean by "has the SOAP Envelop as below"? Also: what is your actual question?